# Item name in array 2d / multidimensional

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How to assign a name to element in multidimensional array in Actionscript 3.

In 1d array working:

```
tab[0].name = "name";
```

In multidimensional array dont working:

```
tab[0][0] = "name";
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What are the elements in the array? What happens in the second example? Also, in the second one why aren't you using the '.name' property like you do in the first (tab[0][0].name = "name";)?

Comment: Why are you using the name property at all. I can see you are probably coming from an AS2 background, because you are using "name". You don't really use name at all in AS3, there is no need for it.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure you are adding your object properly to the multidimensional array, something like:

```
// Declare a single dimension array
var tab:Array = new Array(); 

// Add another array at each of your indexes, starting at zero
tab[0] = new Array();
tab[0].add(objectThatHasANameProperty);
//OR
tab[0] = new Array(objectThatHasANameProperty)

//Then reference it properly (with the .name, your example code above does not have ".name")
tab[0][0].name = "name";
```

Optionally you can have additional properties defined as follows, if for example you have objects that do not have a name property (not my first choice, but do-able):

```
tab[0] = new Array(someObject, "name", "description");
tab[0][1] = "a new name";
trace(tab[0][1]); //traces: "a new name"
trace(tab[0][2]); //traces: "description"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr:Array =[];
arr[0]=[];
arr[0][0] = "benny";
arr[0][1] = "geo";
trace(arr[0][0]);
```

try this way...